# Rails - Wrong ID when partial is rendered with JS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm using Ajax in Rails to create/destroy a reservation.

The problem is when I try to remove the reservation, some times the reservation ID is showed as the same, and not the last one created.

This issue occurs after I delete a reservation and try to create others.

Here is the code:

```
# controllers/reservation_controller.rb
def create
  @reservation = Reservation.new(reservation_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @reservation.save
      format.html { redirect_to @reservation }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @reservation }
      format.js   { render :layout => false }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @reservation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      format.js   { render :layout => false }
    end
  end
end

def destroy
  @day  = @reservation.day
  @hour = @reservation.hour
  @reservation.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to reservations_url }
    format.json { head :no_content }
    format.js   { render :layout => false }
  end
end
```

The view part:

```
<% hours.each do |hour| %>
  <tr>
      <th><%= hour %></th>
      <% days.each do |day| %>
        <td>
          <% reservation = get_reservation(day.downcase, hour) %>
          <% if reservation %>
            <% if reservation.user_id == current_user.id %>
              <%= render :partial => 'reserved_room', :locals => { reservation: reservation } %>
            <% else %>
              Reserved to <%= reservation.user.name %>
            <% end %>
          <% else %>
              <%= render :partial => 'available_room', :locals => { day: day, hour: hour } %>
          <% end %>
        </td>
      <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

The partial:

```
<%= link_to "Reserved to #{reservation.user.name}", 
  {controller: :reservation, action: :destroy, id: reservation.id}, method: :delete, remote: true, :class => 'cancel_reservation' %>
```

And the JS:

```
$('.create_reservation').bind('ajax:success', function() {
  $(this).parent().html('<%= j render :partial => 'reserved_room', :locals => { reservation: @reservation } %>');
});
```

The project can be tested [here](http://bio-ritmo-agenda-de-sala.herokuapp.com/usuarios/sign_in).

Comment: What's the error? Also where do you assign `@reservation`?

Comment: The error is the ID number, sometimes all new created reservation points to the same ID. It seems that they don't point to the last reservation created but to the same, and when I delete one of them, the others shows the error: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Reservation with 'id'=12). I posted the URL to test.